# Improving contour plots in Python

Tags: python, imshow

I have a plot showing varying depth of a small body of water made in python but the detail isn't as good as I want it. Is there a way to modify my current code to make a plot of the depth of an area with good resolution?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import csv 

x=[]
y=[]
z=[]   
with open('EP_Aug2015.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        x1 = row[0]
        y1 = row[1]
        z1 = row[2]
        x.append(x1)
        y.append(y1)
        z.append(z1)

xmin=float(min(x)) 
xmax=float(max(x)) 
ymin=float(min(y))
ymax=float(max(y))
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:30j, ymin:ymax:30j]
points = [[x[i], y[i]] for i in range(len(x))]
#[row[0] for row in values]
grid_z= griddata(points, z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

plt.contourf(grid_z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This is what the plot looks like
[image]

MATLAB script

```
EPdata= csvread('EP_Aug2015.csv',1,0);

%Create x,y,z values
x=EPdata(:,1);
y=EPdata(:,2);
z=EPdata(:,3);

%Make a range of x and y data points for contour
xi=linspace(min(x),max(x),30);
yi=linspace(min(y),max(y),30);

%Mesh the x and y data
[XI YI]=meshgrid(xi,yi);

%Interpolate original data with the meshed data range
ZI=griddata(x,y,z,XI,YI);

%Contour meshed data
contourf(XI,YI,ZI)
xlabel('Easting');
ylabel('Northing');
colorbar;
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem? How is the resolution not good enough when the data is what it is?

Comment: I don't want my data smoothed. I initially did it on MATLAB and the results were infinitely more detailed. I can't figure out how to add more than one photo or I'd show it.

Comment: Don't do interpolation.

Comment: Well when you survey a pond, you normally don't obtain EVERY SINGLE elevation point in your area because time is money. So you get representative elevations knowing that you can use interpolation to plot the rest of the data. I don't have a complete data set, so do you have a useful suggestion? Interpolation works well in MATLAB, so obviously interpolating is not the issue.

Comment: Post your supposedly equivalent MATLAB code and let's compare them.

Answer (score 2):

Three things jump out at me right away.

1. You are interpolating with many more values in the Python version (100x100 vs 30x30).
2. You are using cubic interpolation in Python and linear in MATLAB.
3. You are plotting with `contourf` in MATLAB but `imshow` in Python, rather than using `contourf` in Python as well.

So I would first use the same interpolation resolution, same interpolation method, and same plotting function in both cases.  If there is still a difference, you will probably need to post or provide a link to some sample data because it is hard to tell.

Also, you should be using `pandas.read_csv` to load the data.

Comment: I didn't convert the original x,y,z data to floats... So it was plotting the string values.